# passing objects to return results in an error

Tags: r

I expected the following code to return the lower and upper bounds of a 95% confidence interval:

```
confint95 = function(mean, se)
{
  confint = abs(se*1.96)
  lower = abs(mean-cint)
  upper = abs(mean+cint)
  return(lower,upper) 
}
```

But this gives this message:

> Error in return(lower, upper) : multi-argument returns are not permitted

How can I set function to return the lower and upper bounds of a 95% confidence interval?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Function will return the last expression. If you think for a moment without `return`. If you gave the function as the last expression to be evaluated

```
lower, upper
```

it would produce an error. If you have IDE it would also probably complain about a syntax error. You would solve that by combining the two elements with a `c` as @Andrie indicated. Ergo, you need to pass a single object. I often use lists to output different data structures. In your case, a vector is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

to reurn two or more results, use "c"

```
dummy <- function(){
  a <- 1
  b <- 22
  return(a,b)
}

dummy()

# Error in return(a, b) : multi-argument returns are not permitted

dummy2 <- function(){
  a <- 1
  b <- 22
  return(c(a,b))
}

dummy2()
# [1]  1 22
```